# Node.js issues with zsh

Tags: node.js, npm, zsh

I'm running Ubuntu via WSL. I originally had the bash shell running but switched to zsh. Node.js was installed on bash and was up to date. I tried to npm install on a project and noticed that node wasn't installed for zsh. So, I went to install node on zsh but it was never installing the latest version of node and whenever I tried running npm, I would get `zsh: command not found: npm`.

I've tried uninstalling node from zsh and reinstalling but it still installs an older version of node for some reason and without npm. I used `sudo apt install nodejs` and tried `sudo apt install npm`. Nothing changed.

Comment: Changing the shell does not change the location of your executables.  Is it possible you have an "alias" in your bash rc files that didn't get ported?

Comment: In bash, use `which node` to see where your node command is located. Then in ZSH, check your `$PATH` variable to see if node is in your ZSH path.

Answer (score 0):

usually, by default it will use bash

to import all available command from bash, you can do:

open `~/.zshrc` using any editor, and put this in the beginning of `~/.zshrc`

```bash
source /home/YOUUSERNAME/.bash_profile
```

and if you only need to add node, do this in your bash

```bash
'export NODE_PATH=~/local/:~/local/node_modules' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. When Oh My ZSH was installed, the path to the installed node and nvm files from bash was not linked for some reason. I had to add `export PATH=/home/MYUSERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.1/bin:$PATH` to the top of the zshrc file. Added it directly below the top commented line that says "If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH. I also commented out the old PATH just in case I needed it for some reason in the future.

The zshrc file can be accessed for editing using `nano ~/.zshrc`.

Your current zsh file path can be found using `echo $PATH`
To change the shell back to bash to get your path use `chsh -s /bin/bash`
Use `echo $PATH` in bash and locate the path for your node (mine was at the start of the path). Copy this small section of the full path to use for your zshrc file.

Switch back to zsh using `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.

The current terminal you are using can be found using `echo $0`